# Why can the null conditional operator be used when setting the value of a bool without using a nullable bool?

Tags: c#, boolean, nullable, null-conditional-operator

I have the following line of code:

```
user.Exists = await this.repository?.Exists(id);
```

`Exists` on the left hand side is a property of the `User` class. Its type is just `bool`, not `bool?`. The `Exists` method on the right hand side is an API method to check if a given entity exists in the repository. It returns `Task<bool>`. I want to check if the repository is null first so I use the null conditional operator. I thought that if the repository is null then the whole right hand side would just return null, which cannot be assigned to a `bool` type, but the compiler seems to be fine with it. Does it just default to a false value somehow?

Comment: Tried to actually run this code? If not, try and you'll see. Or imagine what would happen if Exists method returns null instead of Task

Comment: Well, `await` may be throwing off the type checking, but what would you expect the result to be if `repository` is null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the await. The nullable is happening before the await, so it's like `await (this.repository?.Exists(id))`, which, when this.repository is null, turns into `await (null?.Exists(id))`, which turns into `await (null)`, which crashes.  The ?. isn't capable of reaching into the `Task<bool>` and making it `Task<bool?>`.

So you will either get the proper boolean, or an Exception.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks for explaining that. I better change it then.

Comment: @ChadNedzlek - Per your answer on my question, I think it's a good answer and gave me the information I was looking for. I think if you post a particular section of that article the answer will be good and I will upvote & accept. I appreciate your answer :)